# Debugging Windows Phone App Crash

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have setup handler for unhandled exceptions. It does not get fired and app gets crashed.
I enabled console logging with XDE emulator. All that I can see is this error message in console log

```
PID:0E9200B2 TID:0F31015E Exception 'Access Violation' (0xe): Thread-Id=0f31015e (pth=c05208a4), Proc-Id=0e9200b2(pprc=c0558b68) 'TaskHost.exe', VM-active=0e9200b2(pprc=c0558b68) 'TaskHost.exe' 
PID:0E9200B2 TID:0F31015E PC=424c6356(agcore.dll+0x00136356) RA=424c6b16(agcore.dll+0x00136b16) SP=02d6ed58, BVA=000000e6
```

I suspected it could be because of binding updates from non ui threads. I turned off all non ui threads. But I still see this exception rarely when I click an image button in a list box continuously.

Is there a way to enable verbose logging. The above exception message has very little information to debug.